# Repeating checkbox input with nested ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to repeat a nested object and I have a checkbox with a value of true or false.

Here's my code:

```
<accordion-group
    *ngFor='let brand of products'>
    <div *ngFor='let product of brand.products'>
        <div>
           <input type="checkbox" id="{{product.name}}" ngControl="{{product}}" ([ngModel])="product.checked">
             <label
                attr.for="{{product.name}}"
                id="{{product.description}}"
                class="{{product.description}}"
                (click)="onCheck(model)">
             </label>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </accordion-group>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IItxHiXkpocUjLG6NhMy?p=preview -- see that the checkbox doesn't check when the quantity value is updated. I can't get ngModel to work correctly.

Comment: Put a name attribute to the checkboxes. If they are supposed to belong to the same group they should have same names. Also you can make this question more clear if you add a fiddle with this code so we can better understand the problem, seeing the code running and failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `ngControl` should be `fromControlName` according to angular2 RC.5
- ([ngModel]) should be `[(ngModel)]` or used as different one like `[ngModel]` and `(ngModel)` .
- better to use `property Binding using [ ]` while binding id ,name etc dynamicaly as in your case use

> use `[id]="product?.name"` instead of `id="{{product.name}}"`
>
> use `[attr.for]="product?.name"` instead of `attr.for="{{product.name}}"`

seems Rest is fine everything, if still having same issue please reproduce your problem on plunker and post it.

Comment: See plunker linked to in edited question. I need the checkbox to check when the quantity updates but it doesn't work. The ngModel isn't binding the way it should

Comment: you were right. I got my plunker to work. Now I just need to figure out why it doesn't work in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid

```
([ngModel])
```

and should be

```
[(ngModel)]
```

It's called "banana in a box", not "box in a banana" ;-)

Comment: But you see it's helpful :D

Comment: yeah no doubt  :p

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)]="product.checked";

100% working in angular 2